# Custom form fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I know how to create forms in forms.py and views.py using models.py, but to want to create a birthdate field. As everyone knows we can do this `birthdate = models.DateTimeField()`. However, the issue is the user would have to input their birthdate by typing `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS`.

So does anyone here have an elegant way for users to input their birthday?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Tie a date-picker to the birthday input.

See jQuery UI's [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) widget.

The approach is:

1. User picks a date from datepicker widget.
2. The brithday input get's automatically populated as per the selected date.
3. After form submission, the value in the input goes to the backend.

**UPDATE:**

**Example:**

In your template:

```
<form action=".">
    ...
    {{ form.birthdate }}
    ...
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#id_birthdate" ).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

The `id` of the `birthdate` input is definitely going to be `id_birthdate`, because that is how Django assigns `id`s to form fields, so that is what you need to pass in the script's function.

Also, include `jqueryui.js` in your project.

Comment: The problem with the date picker is the that changing the year will take forever since the user must cycle each month. That is why we must have a separate field for day, month and year, but getting that to be displayed individually using django forms is the unknown.

Comment: @AlexStewart In that case, you can always use `changeYear: true` to select year. I've updated my answer. And here's more on customizing the datepicker: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeYear

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for a nicer DateTimeWidget, not the field itself. Secondly, unless it's **really** necesary, you would more likely use a DateField rather than DateTimeField to record user's birthdate ;)

here's just a one example of custom datetime input widget, but there are more:

https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget

in the forms, you would do:

`birthdate = forms.DateTimeField(widget= ...)`

cheers

Comment: Changing this to a `DateField` is a much better idea. I am not familiar with widgets. I will give this a go.

Answer (score 2):

You could use models.DateField and custom DATE_INPUT_FORMATS if needed:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Comment: Good thinking. This is helpful for the use of jquery/javascript solutions.